# On click - find the index of the clicked element - how many times it appeared before?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.productPhoto', function(){
  console.log($(this).prevAll(".productPhoto").length); // * this is photo number 3
});
```

I need to check how many `productPhoto` elements there are **before** the clicked one (= its index)

This is not working because `prevAll` is for *siblings*, and i need to search how many times `productPhoto` appears under some container(not sibling) before the clicked one.

---

So - in the container named `products`, what is the index of `productPhoto` **that clicked** ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, its as simple as  `console.log( $( ".productPhoto" ).index( this ) );`